# error while porting from vc6 to vs2005

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

i am getting the link error, as it worked fine vc6,please do help me on this

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mfcs42.lib'

Answer (score 1):

I think you have one object file or library that depends on VC6's MFC. You should recompile everything with VS2005.

You may also try copying mfcs42.lib from VC6 directory (not sure if that works).

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyb7zzw4.aspx
I suggest going to VS2008, building, correcting errors and then moving on.